# AVFoundation adding audio input mutes audio playback

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I have an app that records audio and video using AVFoundation. I want any audio playback from other apps (or the system) to continue while recording audio in my app, but when adding the input to the session an already playing audio from another app gets magically muted.

The corresponding code looks like this:

```
// set up audio device
if(m_audioenabled) {
  print("Audio enabled")
  if self.m_audioDevice != nil {
    do {
      let audioinput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: self.m_audioDevice!)
      if self.m_session.canAddInput(audioinput) {
        self.m_session.addInput(audioinput)
      }
    } catch _ {
      print("failed adding audio capture device as input to capture session")
    }
  }

  m_audioDataOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
  m_audioDataOutput?.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: self.m_captureSessionQueueAudio)
  if self.m_session.canAddOutput(m_audioDataOutput!){
    self.m_session.addOutput(m_audioDataOutput!)
  }
}
```

If I comment out the call to canAddInput(...) the audio keeps playing, when I call it, audio playback gets muted.

How can I disable that behavior ?

Please note the migrating to another Audio-API is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your `AVAudioSession` is non-mixable (the default, I think). Try activating a mixable audio session before you set up the `AVCaptureSession`:

```
let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
try! session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.mixWithOthers])
try! session.setActive(true)
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but it didn't solve the problem. I tried before and after the session configuration. I also have experimented with "AVAudioSessionCategoryRecord" (w/o Play) but also no success.

Comment: Can you try also setting `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false` on the `AVCaptureSession`? I only just found out about this flag thanks to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51673774/22147