# AVAudioSession configuration to record and play with others

Tags: ios, avfoundation

I want to configure AVAudioSession that I can record video with audio and also play music from Music app (or any other app that is producing sound, typically internet radios apps)

I configure session like this:

```
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: .mixWithOthers)
try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true, with: .notifyOthersOnDeactivation)
```

This works the way that when my recording app is running I can start playing audio from music app and record video (also record audio as well). So far good.

Now, I put my recording app to the background. Music app continues to play. It is fine. But, when my app is coming back from background music app stop its playback. I would like it to continue. So it basically behaves as build in camera app when shooting video. Is there a way to tell the system that I want other app to continue playback?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I have almost met the similar problem and it is almost killed my one-two days for figure outing the problem.

In my case, I am used `AVCaptureSession` for video/audio recording and it has property called `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession`. As per Apple docs

> **automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession:** A Boolean value that indicates whether the capture session automatically changes
>   settings in the app’s shared audio session.
>
> The value of this property defaults to true, causing the capture
>   session to automatically configure the app’s shared **AVAudioSession**
>   instance for optimal recording

So If we are manually setting the `AVAudioSession`, we should set this property as `false` like below,

```
captureSession.automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession = false;
```

Making this property to `false` and setting appropriate `AVAudioSession` categories manually has solved my issue! Hope it will help in your case too!

**Some more Observations on your code**

- There is no need of `.notifyOthersOnDeactivation` flag to activating an audio
  session This flag is used only when deactivating your audio session. That is when you pass a value of `false` in the beActive parameter of the `setActive(_:options:)` instance method. So the below code fine for active a session
  `try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)`
- In default the `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord` category leads
  to a very low volume of background sound. If you want normal volume, need to use the option `.defaultToSpeaker` with `.mixWithOthers` as follows,

  `try? AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, with: [.mixWithOthers, .defaultToSpeaker])`

Oke! then I think It will now work fine if you have done all other stuff properly.

**Note**** I have created a working sample project for your reference and you can found it on [**GitHub Here**](https://github.com/Arunjos/RecordVideoWhileMusic)

Comment: Brilliant answer, so `automaticallyConfiguresApplicationAudioSession` is how you deal with `AVCaptureSession` interrupting other apps! About your sample project: I'm not sure if the asker is using `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`, but do you know how to get rid of the "Recording Stopped" error it gives you when you switch back to the app?

Comment: I am testing this answer now. So far it works, except there is small pause, in about 1 sec, when recording app is going from background to foreground, music pauses and than playback continues.

Comment: @JurajAntas It seems to be a known issue. You can refer the below link,
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35496563/avcapturesession-addinput-causing-glitch-in-background-audio

Comment: Calling this multiple times, `.defaultToSpeaker` option causes the system background music to die.